# How to insert data from shopping cart into the DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I made simple shopping cart using PHP for my website, so now I need to take data from that shopping cart and the form and send it to the DB. I tried writing the code myself but it doesn't work, when I press the submit button nothing happens. What could be the problem?

This is the code I have:

Index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tut");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Top Food-Porucivanje za firme</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="width:60%;">
    <h2 align="center">Top Food kolica</h2>
    <br />
    <form>
    <input type="textbox" name="ime_firme" placeholder="Ime firme">
    <input type="textbox" name="ime" placeholder="Ime">
    <input type="textbox" name="prezime" placeholder="Prezime">
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `p_name`, `image`, `price` FROM `products` WHERE 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <form method="post" action="shop.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
            <div style="border: 1px solid #eaeaec; margin: -1px 19px 3px -1px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05); padding:10px;" align="center">
            <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive">
            <h5 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["p_name"]; ?></h5>
            <h5 class="text-danger"> <?php echo $row["price"]; ?> RSD</h5>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["p_name"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-default" value="Dodaj u kolica">
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <h2>Moja kolica</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th width="40%">Ime proizvoda</th>
    <th width="10%">Kolicina</th>
    <th width="20%">Cena</th>
    <th width="15%">Ukupno</th>
    <th width="5%">Komanda</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td name="ime"><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"] ?> X</td>
            <td> <?php echo $values["product_price"]; ?> RSD</td>
            <td> <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"], 2); ?> RSD</td>
            <td><a href="shop.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Ukloni</span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Ukupno</td>
        <td align="right"> <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?> RSD</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Poruci">
    </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Shop.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tut");
if(isset($_POST["add"]))
{
if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
{
$item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_id");
if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
{
$count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
$item_array = array(
'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
);
$_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
}
else
{
echo '<script>alert("Proizvod je vec u kolicima")</script>';
echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
}
}
else
{
$item_array = array(
'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
);
$_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
}
}
if(isset($_GET["action"]))
{
if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
{
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values)
{
if($values["product_id"] == $_GET["id"])
{
unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
echo '<script>alert("Proizvod je uklonjen")</script>';
echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
}
}
}
}
?>
```

My attempt at sending data into the database:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tut";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO tut (p_name, image, price)
VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ime'])}')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Considering I'm pretty new to PHP and databases, I kind of get what you said. I'll certainly have all of this is mind, but am I at least on the right track with this?

Comment: I'm always *extremely* concerned when people open up Notepad and just have at it to make an e-commerce site. If you're intending to go live with this and handle actual money you have an enormous responsibility to do this right and not expose people to risk. This is why using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) is always a good plan. They come in a variety of forms, from a more minimal one like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to more comprehensive such as [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: It's also worth evaluating if an off-the-shelf e-commerce platform like [Magento](http://magento.com) can't get you 90% of the way there and you can customize it to provide the remaining 10%. Getting a "good enough" e-commerce solution up and running isn't hard. Getting that custom, quirky code that's often full of mistaken assumptions *secure* and *maintainable* is extremely hard. The code you have here is a stew of HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript in no particular order, as is typical with hand-built sites. It's very hard to find flaws and fix them.

Comment: Oh, no, no, this will not be an e-commerce website, I still have a LOT to learn before making that. This will be just so people can see what the company has to offer, all of the transactions will be done in person. I just need a way to get all of the information into the DB. That's why I'm not that concerned, I just need every order to arrive and I'm good. And what you said about the mixture of HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript, yea it's true, but this is just a test so I didn't pay much attention to that, which I probably should have, because it would make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: The one thing a framework will teach you is how to organize your code. It's the difference between unmaintainable chaos and something you can hand off to someone who's already familiar with that platform. The Model-View-Controller separation of concerns is a good example of how these frameworks will force you to think about where an appropriate place is for any given piece of code. Like a well-organized kitchen, the difference is night and day.

Comment: Yes, I'll work on that, especially when asking questions... But now that you know that there will be no sensitive information sent through this, does this look like a beginning, it doesn't even have to be good, just a beginning, just so I know to keep working with this code or to abandon it and start all over.

Comment: It's always a beginning and it's always hard to say for sure where it will go. If you want to have code that's long-lasting and something you can come back to in two years and still make sense of, though, you'll want to steer towards accepted best practices and [common design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). Hand-rolled code is easy to get started with, you just pound in `<?php` and keep going, but it can get exponentially more difficult to add functionality. Frameworks are harder at first but easier over time, they've got your back.

Comment: I wrote this code just to serve me for a couple of months, and I'll have to redo the whole site, looks and everything. But thanks for all of the advice, it helped a lot, especially finding out I will be able to use this code.

Answer (score 0):

submit button is placed outside the form tag, make sure your data is submitted

Comment: But I want to send all the data from the shopping cart, not just the form. If it is going to help I can give you the link to the shopping cart.

Comment: @Pavle Ya please add the link. So that we can help you in better way

Comment: http://topfoodbgd.com/ZaFirme/ If you can't understand something, cause everything is in Serbian, please ask me so I can clarify